# how to split datasets into training and test data with sklearn

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm using at&t faces dataset, a main directory of contains 40 sub-directories, each sub-directory contains different images of a specific person. I created a list that contains the sub-directories names. I want to use the data to train a neural network so I want to split the data into 80% training and 20% testing. Here is what I have done so far :

```
import os
import cv2
path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\att_faces"
directory = []
directory = [x[1] for x in os.walk(path)]
non_empty_dirs = [x for x in directory if x]


directory = [item for subitem in non_empty_dirs for item in subitem]
```

How should I proceed after this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to split your data in to train and test sets. For that, you can either

1. Manually or using a script separate train and test to folders and load them to train with the help of a Data Generator.
2. Load whole data and split them to train and test in memory.

Let's discuss the second option.

> main directory contains 40 sub-directories

Let assume your main directory is `Train//` and there are `40` subfolders namely `1-40`. Also, I assume class label is the folder name.

```
# imports

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# seed for reproducibility
SEED = 44000


# lists to store data
data = []
label = []

# folder where data is placed
BASE_FOLDER = 'Train//'

folders = os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER)

# loading data to lists
for folder in folders:
    for file in os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER + folder + '//'):
        img = cv2.imread(BASE_FOLDER + folder + '//' + file)
        # do any pre-processing if needed like resize, sharpen etc.
        data = data.append(img)
        label = label.append(folder)

# now split the data in to train and test with the help of train_test_split

train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(data, label, test_size=0.2, random_state=SEED)
```